# Import data from python (probleme with where condition)

Tags: python, sql, database, import, where-clause

I work in Python
I have code that allows me to import a dataset that works fine. However in my dataset I have 3 different patients and I would like to import only the patient that interests me (possible by adding the WHERE statement in the SQL query.
So the following code works:

```
def importecdata():
query2 = "SELECT TECDATA.[Vol_Recalage_US_VD], TECDATA.[Vol_Recalage_Us_VG], TECDATA.[SUBJID] FROM TECDATA  INNER JOIN MEDDATA ON TECDATA.DateTime = MEDDATA.DateTime WHERE TECDATA.[SUBJID]='patient14';"
dftec1 = pd.read_sql(query2, sql_conn, chunksize=100000)
dftec = pd.concat(dftec1)
return(dftec)
```

It return the patient 14 data
But now I want to put the patient's name as a variable in my function so I made the following code:

```
def importecdata(patient):
query2 = "SELECT TECDATA.[Vol_Recalage_US_VD], TECDATA.[Vol_Recalage_Us_VG], TECDATA.[SUBJID] FROM TECDATA  INNER JOIN MEDDATA ON TECDATA.DateTime = MEDDATA.DateTime WHERE TECDATA.[SUBJID]=patient;"
dftec1 = pd.read_sql(query2, sql_conn, chunksize=100000)
dftec = pd.concat(dftec1)
return(dftec)
```

I chek and the patient variable got the value patient14. But it don't work... i try to modify the value of the variable patient to 'patient14' it don't work too i have the same error :
invalid column name \xa0: 'patient'. So the code works, the problem is from the "where" condition with the patient variable

(sorry for my english i'm french)

Comment: Your second example doesn't have quotation marks while the first does, is that right?

Comment: Yes because the second is a variable which contains the name patient
And in the first example i put directly the name patient in the where condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your patient value in the query string check below code:

```
def importecdata(patient):
    query2 = "SELECT TECDATA.[Vol_Recalage_US_VD], TECDATA.[Vol_Recalage_Us_VG], TECDATA.[SUBJID] FROM TECDATA  INNER JOIN MEDDATA ON TECDATA.DateTime = MEDDATA.DateTime WHERE TECDATA.[SUBJID]='{0}';"
    query2 = query2.format(patient)
    dftec1 = pd.read_sql(query2, sql_conn, chunksize=100000)
    dftec = pd.concat(dftec1)
    return(dftec)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer
But it don't works because the name of my patient in my data is exactly : PA-014-FR-PON (and not patient14 i tell it just for the example) 
I have this error when i try your code : 
unknow column name 'PA' unknow column name 'FR' unknow column name 'PON'

Comment: @NabilKl Sorry I forgot to add single qoutes around patient. Please check updated answer `{0}` is now `'{0}'`